# A very basic question about the concept of feedback in oscillators

Tags: oscillator

This is a conceptual beginner question. I'm novice about the oscillators. But I'm trying to understand the idea behind.
See for instance the following paragraph:

[image]

I can understand the idea of feeding back the equal amount of lost energy to the input to keep oscillations continuous. This is like when we give a push to swing to make the swinging continuous. And for that we should give the push at the right instant and with right amount of force.

But in the case of the circuit I guess they don't just tie the input to the output. There must be something between the input and output which decides how much amount of the output must be fed back to the input. And this has to be very precise.

Let's say I'm the interface which does this job between the output and the input. I'm the responsible unit to keep the oscillations continuous. And lets say I have the ability to sense the input voltage and output voltage anytime. What do I do with these info and process and find out the exact energy needs to be fed back?

Comment: Are you asking about positive feedback with the purpose of designing an oscillator, or are you asking how to feed a resonating LC circuit?

Comment: I'm asking how is that feedback implemented and how can it know and decide how much amount of the output should be fed back to the input to keep the oscillations stable continuous. How can the feedback unit know how much amount is necessary to be fed back.

Comment: Maybe is more than a beginner question but I though a big view could be given.

Comment: Lookup negative resistance, in this case the LC combo is the oscillator, then a circuit with negative resistance is added to sustain oscillation

Comment: Approximately, it will be stable regardless of how much energy you feed back, actually, because if you feed extra energy then that increases the oscillation amplitude, which increases the losses, which balances it out again.

Comment: The above is definitely wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Feedback in sinewave oscillators is actually stronger than the exact minimum to keep on the oscillation. Of course the amplitude of oscillations will grow, but in practice there's allways a limit how much they can grow. The amplifier starts to distort and this stops the growth. If one wants pure sinewave, he must filter out the distortion and leave the fundamental. In well designed LC oscillators the LC circuit does this often well enough for several purposes.

A RC circuit in the feedback route can well have enough steep phase shift vs frequency dependence to make the oscillation to happen in a stable enough frequency. But RC filters generally cannot kill the harmonics as efficiently as LC circuits. Low distortion sinewave is still possible if the signal chain has a control circuit, which measures the output power and reduces the feedback or amplifier gain as soon as the output power has reached the wanted value. This is known as automatic gain control (AGC). The amplifier amplifies a little more than is needed for oscillation and the AGC circuit reduces the gain or feedback factor proportionally to the output power.

Very simple AGC solutions (often not more than making the amp clip softly) can produce a sinewave which seems perfect in oscilloscope. This is not enough for distortion measurements of high quality amplifiers, much cleaner sinewave is needed. To get it one needs a well designed control system to do the AGC. (+low distortion amp in the oscillator, too).

Here's an example of RC sinewave oscillator with AGC circuit. AGC circuit has so called PI controller which searches the exact needed gain.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the part about feeding the LC circuit. AS it's not clear to me what you would otherwise be asking.

Consider an LC circuit in resonance with some losses:

[image]

This resonant circuit is fed very near it's resonance frequency.

No let's look at the transient analysis of this agitated LC circuit:
[image]

Ignore the first 20ms, that's the simulation finding it's DC operating equilibrium. You se current through L in green and power supply in blue.

That's what happens, just like that! Because the LC circuit swings at resonance, current and voltage across L and C are high and the circuit finds it's natural equilibrium when voltage across teh LC circuit is equal to the voltage of the power source. The power source does however deliver very little power to the LC circuit, because the current through the source is very small. If you increase the load in series as R1 or in parallel across L1 and C1, you will see that V1 current increases.

If you'r looking for feedback, it is there but not explicitly. The feedback in this case is the voltage across the LC resonant circuit. But its enforced here by V1. Nevertheless, current of V1 is very small.

Let's start here, I'm not suer fi this is what you wanted to know.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not what I ask. It doesn't have to be LC btw. It is about "feedback" part. It can be any oscillator. Im asking if you were the feedback unit of an osc. circuit who is responsible to decide the amount of energy to be fed back to the input to keep the oscillations continuous. In that case how would you measure how much energy is lost and how would you feed it back to the input. How is that feedback unit is accomplishing this task.

Comment: panic-attack, for designing/analyzing any oscillator circuit it is best NOT to speak about feedback energy but to use the existing oscillation criterion which is given in the frequency domain (see my detailed answer)..

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this (IMHO) is to consider the gain margin of the open loop.

For a negative feedback system, we look at the open loop gain at the frequency where the open loop phase angle is \$\small -180^0\$. If the gain at this frequency is unity, the closed loop will be critically stable; if the gain is \$\small >1\$, the closed loop will be unstable; and if the gain is \$\small <1\$, the closed loop will be stable.

The reason that this works is because in negative feedback the open loop \$\small -180^0\$ phase angle becomes \$\small -360^0 = 0^0\$, due to the output being shifted  further \$\small 180^0\$ by the negative sign in the comparator when the loop is closed (or the inverting input in the case of an opamp in negative feedback).

With the positive feedback system considered here, the open loop has a gain of, say, \$\small K\$ and a phase shift of \$\small 0^0\$. But what happens to this phase shift with the +ve feedback?? Nothing - it remains at \$\small 0^0\$ - exactly the same as the negative feedback case!

We can now apply the gain margin rule for stability: if \$\small K<1\$ the closed loop will be stable.

Let's try it: let \$\small x\$ and \$\small y\$ be the input and output signals, respectively and let \$\small K=0.5\$. The closed loop equation is:
$$0.5(y+x)=y $$ hence $$0.5(y+x)=y $$ $$0.5y=0.5x $$ giving $$y=x $$

To verify, let \$\small x=100\$, thus  \$\small y=100 \$, hence:  $$\small 0.5(100+100)=100 $$

Another example: let \$\small x=4\$, and \$\small K=0.9 \$.

Thus:
$$\small 0.9(x+y)=y $$
$$\small y=9x=36 $$

To verify:

$$\small 0.9(4+36)=36 $$

This holds for any \$\small 0 \leq K \lt 1\$, and also for any input magnitude.

Note, if \$\small K = 1\$ we have an oscillator, and if \$\small K \gt 1\$ we have an unstable closed loop.

Comment: Chu, what do you think: What will the circuit do when the closed loop is "unstable"?? What does this mean - in contrast to the case you have named "critically stable", K=1 ?

Comment: Are you asking what happens with an ideal op amp, having no lags or delays?

Comment: Chu - No, it is a more or less polemic question. Sorry. To me - the situationis as follows: K=1 is an idealistic case, which never can be realized by design.Hence we always make K>1 and the oscillation will start. However, the amplitude is rising continuously and we will have either  hard-clipping (supply rail) or soft-limiting (diodes or something else). Hence, we have an oscillator for K>1 (start period) as well as for K=1 (amplitude limiting). Both cases are connected very closely.

Comment: My only point was: Your term "unstable closed-loop" tells us nothing about what is really happening (oscillation yes/no)?

Answer (score 0):

For my opinion, the most simple and clear answer can be given in the frequency domain. In this domain, the classical oscillation criterion was formulated by H. Barkhausen.

The principle of a working oscillator is a closed feedback loop. However, this criterion is applied to the system when the loop is opened at a suitable node.

Barkhausen Criterion: If a circuit with feedback shall oscillate it is necessary that the loop gain (that is the gain of the open loop) is exactly unity. That means, the magnitude must be unity and the phase of the complete loop (including a possible phase invesion at the summing feedback node) must be zero. This condition must be valid for one single frequency only.

In practice, the magnitude of the loop gain must be slightly larger than unity (app. 1.2...1.5) because (a) it is, in practice, not possible to design a loop gain of exactly unity and (b) we need a safe start of oscillations.

In this case, the oscillation amplitude will rise until it is limited - either due to the finite supply voltages of the active devices (hard limiting, amplitude clipping) or bebause of some non-linearities within the feedback loop which cause "soft limiting" (Diodes, Fet as a resistor..). In the latter case, a good quasi-sinusoidal form can be preserved.

Comment (loop gain): For measuring or simulating the loop gain (in order to check if the criterion is met) it is necessary to open the loop at a node which is "suitable". What does this mean? For a correct measurement/simulation it is essential that opening the loop (1) does not destroy the bias condion of the active device (which often is definded by dc feedback) and (2) does not change the loading conditions at the opening node. In many practical cases, this can be fulfilled if we select the low-resistive output of an operational amplifier for opening the loop.

If - for a given circuit - these conditiones cannot be fulfilled some specific test arrangements are described in the literature for excat loop gain simulation (Middlebrook`s method).